# How to find the location URL in a Django response object?

Tags: django, httpresponse, http-response-codes

Let's say I have a Django response object.

I want to find the URL (location).
However, the response header does not actually contain a Location or Content-Location field.

How do I determine, from this response object, the URL it is showing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The response does not decide the url, the request does.

The response gives you the content of the response, not the url of it.

Comment: But if there's a redirect, the request doesn't know.

Comment: @Joseph Turian: sure it does, it's in the referrer header: `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Comment: @JosephTurian: the request is for reading data from the client, the response is for sending data to the client. You can't tell a client what url he is on because he already gave you that data. You can tell the client to redirect to a different page though.

Comment: So, the URL that was requested, if it was after a redirect, is lost forever. The client doesn't keep it as state and doesn't add it the response.

Answer (score 10):

This is old, but I ran into a similar issue when doing unit tests.  Here is how I solved the problem.

You can use the `response.redirect_chain` and/or the `response.request['PATH_INFO']` to grab redirect urls.

Check out the documentation as well!  [Django Testing Tools: assertRedirects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects)

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.test import TestCase


class MyTest(TestCase)
    def test_foo(self):
        foo_path = reverse('foo')
        bar_path = reverse('bar')
        data = {'bar': 'baz'}
        response = self.client.post(foo_path, data, follow=True)
        # Get last redirect
        self.assertGreater(len(response.redirect_chain), 0)
        # last_url will be something like 'http://testserver/.../'
        last_url, status_code = response.redirect_chain[-1]
        self.assertIn(bar_path, last_url)
        self.assertEqual(status_code, 302)
        # Get the exact final path from the response,
        # excluding server and get params.
        last_path = response.request['PATH_INFO']
        self.assertEqual(bar_path, last_path)
        # Note that you can also assert for redirects directly.
        self.assertRedirects(response, bar_path)
```

Comment: I got here trying to find out about the path of a response. But it doesn't seem like `HttpResponse` have method called `request` or `redirect_chain`. reverse works for getting the url though.

Comment: Forgetting the `follow=True` is a very bad thing indeed. You didn't, I did. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10971

Comment: The `PATH_INFO` is not accurate. It'll have port set to 80 even if no port was set in the URL, so, it's not a definite way of rebuilding the URL.